# Ruby on Rails: How to transfer dynamic data from server to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, client-server

RoR has controllers that render views. One day I wanted a controller not only to render a specific view, but also to run some javascript code using data from contoller (**@product**, for example) after rendering.

## 1. Inline javascript

So I went to my **products/show.html.erb** and wrote something like:

```
<%= javascript_tag "alert('#{@product.name} is just awesome!')" %>
```

## 2. Assets with server data

But we're all grown up boys and know about **unobtrusive javascript**, so I included some javascript files to my layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{params[:controller]}/#{params[:action]}" %>
```

and then went to **app/assets/javascripts/products/show.js.erb** and wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('<%= @product.name%> is just awesome!');
});
```

But than I remembered that assets are being precompiled in production and continued to think.

## 3. HTML data attributes

Another way to pass some data to javascript is by using html5 data attributes in view files:

```
<div class="product" data-product-name="<%= @product.name %>">
```

Then in your asset you can write something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('*[data-product-name]').each(
    alert($(this).data('product-name') + ' is just awesome!');
  );
});
```

## 4. One more request to server

Anyway if you want to be able to cache your view files and assets, it seems as if the only way to transfer data to javascript is by using an additional Ajax request. I wonder if it is good practice to create a separate action that will send **@product** to client?

Can anyone say, what is the nicest way to send data from server to a javascript while rendering a view and why?